# calculation inside char value

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have string value like "*some text {5+1.5}*", and would like to calculate it inside data step. (This value is from column, but it doesn't matter).

I have code, that was executed correctly but with errors inside macro. But if execute it without macro, there is no errors. I would like to execute it inside macro, how can i fix error? Without using `options NOERRORABEND NODMSSYNCHK NOSYNTAXCHECK;`. Algorithm is to change using `tranwrd` `"{"` to `"%sysevalf("` and `"}"` to `")"`.

**CODE THAT WORK CORRECTLY, BUT THERE IS ERROR IN LOG:**

```
%macro t;
data have_in_macro;
%let value=%sysfunc(tranwrd(
                          %sysfunc(tranwrd(
                                        "some text {5+1.5}",%str(}),%str(%))
                              )),%str({),%str(sysevalf)%str(%()
                ));

                %let value=%sysfunc(tranwrd(
                            %str(&value),%str(sysevalf),%str(%%)%str(sysevalf)
                ));
                t=&value;
run;
%mend t;

%t;
```

**CODE THAT WORK CORRECTLY WITHOUT ERRORS, BUT WITHOUT USING MACRO:**

```
data have;
%let value=%sysfunc(tranwrd(
                          %sysfunc(tranwrd(
                                        "some text {5+1.5}",%str(}),%str(%))
                              )),%str({),%str(sysevalf)%str(%()
                ));

                %let value=%sysfunc(tranwrd(
                            %str(&value),%str(sysevalf),%str(%%)%str(sysevalf)
                ));
                t=&value;
run;
```

INPUT:

> some text {5+1.5}

OUTPUT:

> some text 6.5

ERROR USING MACRO:

> ERROR: %SYSEVALF must be followed by an expression enclosed in
> parentheses.

**P.S. This code is just sample to call error that i get using my algorithm calling `tranwrd`.**

Comment: The two %LET statements will be executed before the data step starts running so it would be clearer to humans reading the program if they were placed before the data statement.

Comment: @Tom i am reading dataset before execution the data step, using `getvarc` and `open`, so  %let statement just for calling error like i get.

Comment: Not sure how your reply makes any difference to my comment. Are you saying you are using macro logic to read data from a dataset and generate data step code to create another dataset?  If so then make sure to generate output statements if you want the generated dataset to have more than one observation.

Comment: yes, sure. i generate output statements, thanx:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a `data _null_` step you can use data step functions, not macro functions.

This works for me - no errors.

I broke it into two lines one to replace the `{` with `%sysevalf(` and `}` with `)`.

EDIT: Use RESOLVE() to evaluate the string.

```
data have;
yourStringVariable = "some text {5+1.5}";
run;
    
  %macro t(input_dsn= , output_dsn = );  
    data &output_dsn.;
    set &input_dsn.;
     *replace {;
     text_string2 = tranwrd(yourStringVariable, '{', '%sysevalf(');
     *replace };
     text_string3 = resolve(tranwrd(text_string2, '}', ')'));

    run;
    
%mend t;

%t(input_dsn=have, output_dsn=want);;

proc print data=want;
run;
```

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear in question, but i need to output it in dataset variable and inside macro;(

Comment: That's even easier :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `tranwrd` invocations from macro are overly complicated and the `%` you introduced with `sysevalf` came AFTER instead of before.

The code sample (farther below) has a simpler expression that resolves the hard-coded

```
"some text {5+1.5}"
```

into an internal intermediate

```
"some text %sysevalf(5+1.5)"
```

within the context of outer most `%sysfunc`.  Because the outer most is `%SYSFUNC`, and NOT `%QSYSFUNC` the macro system will, implicitly, further resolve the intermediated into a final macro assignment of symbol `value` as

```
 "some text 6.5"
```

Sample code:

```
%macro t;
data have_in_macro;

    %let value = %sysfunc(tranwrd(
                          %sysfunc(tranwrd(
                                          "some text {5+1.5}",
                                          },
                                          %str(%))
                                          )
                          ),
                          {,
                          %nrstr(%sysevalf%()
                ));

%put NOTE: (MACRO &sysmacroname.) value=%superq(value);

                t=&value;
run;
%mend t;

%t

ods listing;

proc print data=have_in_macro;
run;
```

Log

```
308  %t
NOTE: (MACRO T) value="some text 6.5"

NOTE: The data set WORK.HAVE_IN_MACRO has 1 observations and 1 variables.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           0.00 seconds
      cpu time            0.01 seconds
```

Output

```
The SAS System

Obs          t

 1     some text 6.5
```